# Jupyter Notebook on AWS does not connect to kernels

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook

I've installed Jupyter Notebook on AWS (Ubuntu 14.04). The notebook runs, however, does not connect to kernels:

[image: kernel]

The shell output:

```
[I 15:00:22.857 NotebookApp] Kernel interrupted: 805928a8-674d-458f-b990-d86bd3c26711
[I 15:01:24.459 NotebookApp] Saving file at /Notebooks/R Example.ipynb
[I 15:01:37.533 NotebookApp] Creating new notebook in /Notebooks
[W 15:01:38.626 NotebookApp] 404 GET /nbextensions/nbpresent/js/nbpresent.deps.min.js.js (35.211.41.196) 1.86ms referer=https://22.133.12.196:8888/notebooks/Notebooks/Untitled.ipynb?kernel_name=python3
[I 15:01:38.656 NotebookApp] Kernel started: 0a9a882e-1e55-4913-8640-8213c1aae88f
[I 15:01:58.721 NotebookApp] Kernel restarted: 0a9a882e-1e55-4913-8640-8213c1aae88f
```

What may the cause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changed Browser from Safari to Chrome and everything worked fine. Read in other posts, that Safari don't like my self made certificate.

Comment: Q: What may the cause? A: Safari does not 'like' self made certificate.

Comment: Confirmed that this solution works. The kernel connects after changing from Safari to Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: After hours of looking around, this has something to do with the websockets. All notebooks have some sort of websockets that connect to a backend service. If you are using a load balancer in front of your notebook server, make sure to use TCP instead of HTTP/HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to add the missing Python kernel in Jupyter Notebook in Ubuntu 14.04 with *ipykernel*.

Jupyter Notebook on my Ubuntu runs only Python 3 by default. If you're running Jupyter on Python 3, you can set up a Python 2 kernel like this:

```
python2 -m pip install ipykernel
python2 -m ipykernel install --user
```

Start the notebook server from the terminal:

jupyter notebook

You should see Jupyter Notebook open in your web browser.
If you're running Jupyter on Python 2, you can set up a Python 3 kernel like this:

```
python3 -m pip install ipykernel
python3 -m ipykernel install --user
```

After you have done this, you will get to choose between either of the two kernels in the Jupyter Notebook interface.

---

#### Ubuntu 20.04 and later

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install python3-notebook jupyter jupyter-core
```

#### Ubuntu 18.04-19.10

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install python3-notebook jupyter jupyter-core python-ipykernel
```

To start the notebook server run the following command:

```
jupyter notebook
```

You should see Jupyter Notebook open in your web browser.

Alternatively you can use Google Colaboratory instead of Jupyter Notebook. Google Colaboratory is Google's free Jupyter notebook environment that requires no setup and runs entirely in the cloud.